# Visual C# Datagrid returning all records from database

Tags: c#

I want to display a datagrid that will return records based on a query from my search button but whenever I click the search button, it returns all the records from the database.

*HTML*

```
<html>
<asp:TextBox ID="ClientCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:GridView ID="ClientDataGrid" runat="server" Height="111px" 
Width="202px" Visible="False"></asp:GridView>
```

*C#*

```
private void rep_bind()
    {
        connection();
        string query = ""select * from client where client_code ='" + 
        ClientCode.Text + "'"; 
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ClientDataGrid.DataSource = ds;
        ClientDataGrid.DataBind();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

    }

    protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
        connection();
        string query = string.Format("select * from client where client_code  
         ='" + ClientCode.Text + "'") ; ;

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = 
        category.SelectedItem.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        ListItem selectedItem = category.SelectedItem;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ClientCode.Text) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ClientName.Text)) 

       {
          ClientDataGrid.Visible = false;
          Label1.Visible = true;
          Label1.Text = "Please Enter Correct Search Values";
       } 

       else if (dr.HasRows)
       {
          dr.Read();
          rep_bind();
          ClientDataGrid.Visible = true;
       }
       else
       {
          ClientDataGrid.Visible = false;
       }
    }
```

I want to display records that will match the client code on the text box but it always return all the records from the database.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Just posted it, sorry I'm new to this

Comment: You should use a parameter for client_code as well to avoid concatenating a string into the query (which is a sql injection risk). Does ClientCode.Text actually have a value when you debug?

Comment: yes it has a value

Comment: i edited the code(changed LIKE to "="), Kindly check it.

Comment: I think i have just solved my initial problem. Now I am wondering about the Parameter and the SQL injection risk that you are talking about. Can you expound a bit more @pmcilreavy? I'm very new to programming and still has a lot to learn, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment on the actual question so I'll ask it here.

You seem to be executing the same query twice. Once to see if it has any rows and the second time to fill the data grid. You can change this so that the query is executed only once.

One way to prevent SQL injection attacks is to use a Stored Procedure instead of directly creating the query using string interpolation. Use a stored procedure and pass your conditions using parameters.

Here's a link that explains how to create one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

How about this version?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand sCommand;
        SqlDataAdapter sAdapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
        DataSet sDs;
        DataTable sTable;        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Stores";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
            sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sDs = new DataSet();
            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores");
            sTable = sDs.Tables["Stores"];
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["Stores"];
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            save_btn.Enabled = false;
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }

        private void new_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
            save_btn.Enabled = true;
            new_btn.Enabled = false;
            delete_btn.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void delete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            }
        }

        private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            save_btn.Enabled = false;
            new_btn.Enabled = true;
            delete_btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```